# calculating YearWeek from Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to correctly calculate working Year/Week number from a date field.

I tried to use the clock format command as follows

```
% clock format [clock scan "2016.01.01" -format "%Y.%m.%d"] -format "%Y-WW%V"
2016-WW53
```

and while the Week number is correct, the year is not because in this case Jan1 lands in week 53, as it did in 2016.  Since the `Tcl` clock format command specifies the week number and the year separately, I end up with `Jan 1, 2016` being shown as `2016-WW53` but this should be shown as `2015-WW53`.

Is there a built in function for this or do I need to use an if/then condition to choose the year correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the modifier `%G`:

```
clock format [clock scan "2016.01.01" -format "%Y.%m.%d"] -format "%G-WW%V"
```

Output:

```
2015-WW53
```

From the manual:

> **%G**
>   On output, produces a four-digit year number suitable for use with the week-based ISO8601 calendar; that is, the year number corresponds to the week number produced by %V. On input, accepts such a four-digit year number, possibly with leading whitespace.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I didn't read the documentation carefully enough.